# How to select two input fields at once and check if they are filled?

Tags: javascript

So I am making a game and I need to check if these two HTML `<input>` fields have some data before I do an `alert();` saying that they won. Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this and I have been stuck at it for hours, please do help, attaching a screenshot for assistance.

**In the image, I want to constantly monitor the 2 empty `<input>` fields and once there is data IN BOTH, then I want to throw up an `alert();`**

*Here's what I tried:*

```
var firstLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0].value.length;
var secondLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value.length;

if (!firstLetterField && !secondLetterField) {
  console.log("Please ignore this message: NOT_FILLED...");
} else {
  alert("That's right! The word was " + spellingOfWord.join("").toUpperCase() + "! Thanks for playing!");
  window.location.href = "/";
}
```

[image: "JS-Hangman"]

Comment: Hey there and welcome to SO. It would help if you include your HTML that goes with the JavaScript so we can get the complete picture.

Comment: Also, when are you running the above code? Are you running it when the user clicks a buttons? Performs an action of some sort? Or just when the page loads?

Comment: ```if (firstLetterField && secondLetterField) { /* do alert */ } else { /* not filled */ }```

Comment: @SSa1t Just edited my answer to match the specification you gave as a comment

Answer (score 1):

How about just adding a common class to your user input and use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to perform your check ?

eg

```html
<html>
  <body id="game">
    <input data-expected="m" class="user-input" />
    <input data-expected="a" class="user-input" />

    <div id="keyboard">
      <button>d</button>
      <button>c</button>
      <button>b</button>
      <button>a</button>
      <button>d</button>
      <button>m</button>
      <button>e</button>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".user-input");

    const keyboard = document
      .querySelector("#keyboard")
      .querySelectorAll("button");

    let inputPosition = 0;

    function nextInput() {
      inputPosition += 1;
      if (inputPosition === inputs.length) {
       alert("you won");
      } 
    }

    function handleClick(event) {
      const input = inputs.item(inputPosition);
      const submittedValue = event.target.innerHTML;

      if (input.dataset.expected === submittedValue) {
        input.value = submittedValue;
        setTimeout(nextInput);
      }
    }

    keyboard.forEach((button) => button.addEventListener("click", handleClick));
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: This won't do what OP wants. As mentioned in the question: _I want to constantly monitor the 2 empty <input> fields_

Answer (score 0):

You could register an event-listener and check if your condition is met:

```
var firstLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0];
var secondLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1];

// Function to call when both inputs contain values
function bothReady() {
    console.log("bothReady", firstLetterField.value, secondLetterField.value);
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    // Wait for both fields to have values
    if (firstLetterField.value.length > 0 && secondLetterField.value.length > 0) {
        bothReady();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code just works fine. There were just some mistakes that I noticed.

- You tried to use the length to detect if it is empty. You could instead compare it with an empty string.
- You reversed the boolean value using else. It looks that does the opposite of what you want.
- In the code you showed you didn't actually defined `spellingOfWord`. So I did it for you.
- The location `"/"` is not compatible in every server. So I would recomment replacing it by `"index.html"`.

Here is the code that I just created

```
function input_inputEvent() {
    var firstLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[0].value;
    var secondLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[1].value;
    var thirdLetterField = document.querySelectorAll("input")[2].value;
    if (firstLetterField.length != "" && secondLetterField != "") {
        alert(
           "That's right! The word was " + 
           [firstLetterField,secondLetterField,thirdLetterField].join("").toUpperCase() + 
           "! Thanks for playing!"
        );
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Migats, the letters are buttons which a user clicks, when the user clicks the button, depending on if the letter was correct, the value goes to the input field, now when the user completes the word, I want that alert, if that is not possible, can you suggest me an alternative using something like a Submit button or something?